# Regex Match Javascript Numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have tried a few different techniques to match just numbers from my DIV but keep failing.

Currently my example html looks like the following.

```
<div data-video="22" class="stars starrr"></div>
<div data-video="/test/22" class="stars starrr"></div>
<div data-video="/someother/test/22" class="stars starrr"></div>
```

I need to only match the number in video, but I keep getting it to work with some and failing with others.

**My current code**

```
$(this).data("video").match(/([\d]+)/);
```

**Current Error on first match  The others work**

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: I have added an example above.

Comment: I hope that explains why you get the error: http://jsfiddle.net/ryfgydee/

Answer (score 5):

You need to cast to a string in the first case;

```
var f = $(this).data("video").toString().match(/([\d]+)/);
```

as `typeof $(this).data("video")` is `number` so no `.match`

Comment: you don't need to put `\d` inside a character class. And i think you don't need to have capturing group also.

Comment: Oh you legend, I been scratching my head for hours trying to work out why. Thanks